# Serving a 'create-react-app' made files with Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to change the backend of my React app to be only Flask based, instead of having two different servers ('npm' and 'flask').

The app was created with 'create-react-app' and the current folder structure is:

```
- myapp
  - node_modules
  - src
    - App.js
    - index.js
    - index.css
    - App.css
  - templates
    - index.html
  app.py
  package.json
```

The `app.py` file consists of this code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The thing is, until now on every save, the npm automatically bundled and reloaded all of my changes in the browser. Now, if I make a change, for example, in the 'index.html', the change is visible in the browser. However, if I try to edit my 'App.js', the change isn't visible at all.

From now on, do I need to rebundle the 'App.js' and components by myself everytime I save them?

I'm a bit confused about this one, so any help or advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finish the development process, you should run `npm build` it will create a new folder of static files, named `build`.

Then you can use any server to serve those static files.

If you want to make any  changes, you should do again `npm build`  and it will update the bundled version in the `build` folder

If you wish to use your backend server while developing, `create-react-app` isn't for you. You should do `npm eject`, and then you can do whatever you want

Comment: This cleared my misunderstandings, thanks @Aminadav!